# Basic interface for sorting algorithms classes

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, sorting

I need to program some sorting algorithms, for this I want to have base interface with virtual function `Sort()`. The problem is that I don't really know which type of elements client will use. I only need comparison operator to be available for this type. So, it could be template, but i can't use template and virtual simultaneously. I need advice on architecture of this code.

Also, it would be good to have ability to pass either allocator or memory in case of not inplace sorts. Where I need to insert this part. Maybe as an optional parameter.

May be I don't need classes at all and another kind of program structure suits better. Thanks.

EDIT:
How to use:

```
obj.SetStrategy(specificAlgortihm);
obj.Execute(array);

...

template <class T>
void Obj::Execute(array)
{
  m_Algorithm->Sort(array);
}
```

Comment: `I can't use template and virtual simultaneously` -- why not? And what's wrong with a plain `std::sort` which uses `operator<` (through `std::less`) by default?

Comment: I need it just to learn some algs. And there are a lot of answers here which state that it is impossible to use compile and run time polymorphism. But, probably it is not the case with current C++ version.

Comment: @Cameron: OP states that he can't have a virtual template method.

Comment: It's not clear what you need the "base interface" for. Imagine that you've implemented everything the way you want - how would you use it? Show the calling code: that should clarify the requirements.

Comment: Why do you need a virtual member function at all? Have you considered using templates only?

Comment: Try making your Algorithm class a template, and Sort its virtual member function.